# Парсинг html: как получить словарь из вложенных таблиц?

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

Получаю страницу, нахожу нужные данные, это таблица.

Как разложить данные из таблицы на пару ключ - значение?

Например, с помощью BeautifulSoup:

```html
    <tr>
     <td>
      Принципал
     </td>
     <td>
      МОРТП  "АНЗАСТ"
     </td>
    </tr>
```

Мой код:

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://fedresurs.ru/messages/4073AEF1951F13998374D373A64CB497'

def getpage(lnk):
    with urllib.request.urlopen(lnk) as response:
        html = response.read()
        return html

soup = BeautifulSoup(getpage(url))
table = soup.find('table', class_='mesview')
# print(table.prettify())
for tr in table.find_all('tr'):
    print(tr.td)
```

На выходе получить словарь `key:value`.
Осложняется тем, что в одном tr есть вложенная таблица.

Как ее правильно обработать?

Comment: Ваша цель получить "плоский" (одноуровневый) словарь или вложенный, соответствующий исходной таблице?

Comment: MaxU, "Плоский", а вложенную таблицу преобразовать Бенефициар: Название, Идентификаторы: ИНН, вполне достаточно будет.

Comment: Может ли вложенная таблица иметь более одного бенефициара? И если да то как вы представляете себе сделать из этого плоскую структуру?

Comment: Может, в таком случае просто первого берем. Конечно, если сделать полное соответствие исходным данным - это будет круто, но я, к сожалению не знаю ни того, ни другого способа реализации :(

Answer (score 6):

я всё-таки решил сделать вложенный список для бенефициаров, чтобы не терять информацию. Выбрать из этого списка первый элемент очень просто...

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://fedresurs.ru/messages/4073AEF1951F13998374D373A64CB497'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

data = {}
# iterating tables with the <table class="mesview"> attribute
for tab in soup.find_all('table',
                         attrs={'class':['mesview']}):
    for row in tab.find_all('tr'):
        tmp = row.find_all('td')
        if len(tmp) == 2:
            data[re.sub(r'\s{3,}', '', tmp[0].text.strip())] = \
                re.sub(r'\s{3,}', '', tmp[1].text.strip())

bnfcr = []
# iterating table(s) with the <table class="mandatoryAssessmentTable"> attribute
for tab in soup.find_all('table', attrs={'class':['mandatoryAssessmentTable']}):
    # parsing column names from table's headers
    cols = [col.text for col in tab.find_all('th')]
    for row in tab.find_all('tr'):
        tmp = row.find_all('td')
        if len(tmp) == len(cols):
            bnfcr.append({cols[0]: tmp[0].text.strip(), cols[1]:tmp[1].text.strip()})
data['Бенефициары'] = bnfcr
print(data)
```

Результат:

```
{'': 'Изменяемый срок действия',
 'Бенефициары': [{'Бенефициар': 'МАДОУ № 13 "УМКА"',
   'Идентификаторы': 'ИНН: 5047086394 ОГРН: 1075047010114'}],
 'Гарант': 'БАНК "ВОЗРОЖДЕНИЕ" (ПАО)(ИНН: 5000001042, ОГРН: 1027700540680)',
 'Дата выдачи': '26.12.2016',
 'Дата завершения действия': '02.03.2018',
 'Дата начала действия': '26.12.2016',
 'МАДОУ № 13 "УМКА"': 'ИНН: 5047086394 ОГРН: 1075047010114',
 'Номер гарантии': '063-158-БГ-2016',
 'Обстоятельства выплаты': 'Получение требования Бенефициара с указанием, в чем состоит нарушение Принципалом основного обязательства, в обе
спечение которого выдана гарантия.',
 'Описание основного обязательства': 'Исполнение обязательств по контракту/договору',
 'Принципал': 'МОРТП  "АНЗАСТ"(ИНН: 5047000703, ОГРН: 1025006178010)',
 'Сумма': '947 917.98RUB',
 'Тип сообщения': 'Сообщение о выпуске независимой гарантии',
 'Торги': '№4от16.12.2016'}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Пошел разбираться :)